# aws library dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz not being found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

trying to figure out this issue with an AWS library that just started happening.  Using scala create a local DyanmoDb...

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.io.FileNotFoundException:      http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1836)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1433)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1431)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$URLInput$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:30)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$URLInput$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:30)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$IStreamBuilder$$anonfun$$init$$5.apply(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:44)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$IStreamBuilder$$anonfun$$init$$5.apply(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:44)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$ThreadBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:57)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessImpl$Spawn$$anon$1.run(ProcessImpl.scala:22)
```

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html#DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning) updated the link to serve the zip/tgz over https. Here is the [new link](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are connecting to local, you should use the endpoint directly in your code.

**Node JS Example:-**

```
AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
    credentials : creds
});
```

When you are using the actual AWS DynamoDB service (i.e. not local), the endpoint will be derived automatically using the region. So, you don't need to provide the endpoint (i.e. only region is important when you connect to actual AWS DynamoDB service).

I think you are trying to switch between local and AWS service without having the above change.

Whatever be the language, please use endpoint URL when you try to connect to local DynamoDB.

```
http://localhost:8000
```

The API should have a default method or provision to configure it.

Comment: we have added those to our code but it start returning the error because it is not finding the jar, not sure where/what to set

Comment: What sdk or lib are you using to connect to dynamo? Can you please provide the link?